# How do I get a GROUP_CONCAT column to be greater than 1,024 characters?

Tags: mysql, csv, group-concat

I recently discovered the limitations of GROUP_CONCAT. I have a query with 482 results. I need to get a CSV of all 482 IDs. When I run GROUP_CONCAT, it can only get 147 at a time (with `,10`) left over:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) 
  FROM account 
 WHERE parent_account_id = 707070 
   AND id != parent_account_id;
```

I've tried using `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) 
  FROM account 
 WHERE parent_account_id = 707070 
   AND id != parent_account_id 
 LIMIT 0, 100;
```

But this doesn't work when I try to get the next 100:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) 
  FROM account 
 WHERE parent_account_id = 707070 
   AND id != parent_account_id 
 LIMIT 100, 100;
```

Are there any other SQL tricks for getting a long CSV without me having to export the results to a file and then use regex to replace newlines with commas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+group_concat_max_len  There's a session variable `group_concat_max_len`

Comment: Ah, sorry for the duplicate, but when I typed in my question I did not get that question as a suggestion. I used `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=65535;` as a solution.

Comment: No problem - the magic search term was "truncate" and I had to search 3 times to find it, though I knew it was there.